# Define a circle extent using the circle tool - arcgis javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I  have the following script for drawing a circle and I want to limit the user to a predefined radius:

```
$('#circle').click(function () {
       clearPreviousSearch();
       map.disableMapNavigation();
       $('#run').fadeOut();
       buttonclickvalue = 'circle';
       drawToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Draw.CIRCLE);
         });
```

Where should I specify that I want to define the specific radius using the ArcGIS API script?:

```
var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(null).outline.setColor("blue");
       var gl = new GraphicsLayer({ id: "circles" });
       var geodesic = dom.byId("geodesic");
       map.addLayer(gl);
       map.on("click", function(e) {
         var radius = map.extent.getWidth() / 100;
         var circle = new Circle({
           center: e.mapPoint,
           geodesic: domAttr.get(geodesic, "checked"),
           radius: radius
           });
```

Comment: Are you getting an error, unexpected behavior, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to require the Units module **"esri/units"** and pass the units to the circle this way

```
var circle = new Circle({
       center: e.mapPoint,
       geodesic: domAttr.get(geodesic, "checked"),
       radius: 100, 
       radiusUnit:units.MILES
});
```

More info on units [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/units-amd.html)

Comment: Everything in esri/units maps to a string, so instead of the extra code, you could use the string directly. For miles, it's "esriMiles". The rest are:  http://i.imgur.com/wCM71id.png

Comment: Sorry but how do I use the string directly?

Comment: instead of units.MILES you put in "esriMiles"